# Angular 6 - *ngIf condition on input is something add attr readonly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to add a condition to an input where is a variable = view then I add the readonly attr to the input.

This is what I'm trying:

```
<input *ngIf="mode == 'view' readonly">
```

This is not working at the moment.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: NgIf is for hiding and showing the whole element, and that syntax for the expression is totally invalid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
<input [readonly]="mode == 'view'">
```

It will add attribute readonly only when mode is equal to view